# Running df -kh command on window to generate nice alligned output to store in ms-excel. help need to format the output

Tags: linux, unix, putty

i am running df -kh command on windows machine using Putty.i need the output in nice format so that I can store the result in microsoft excel.So i need help to to allign the output properly. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df -Ph | column -t
```

Usually, the result is much nicer.

Comment: Thanks...I tried it gives same result as the one which I have mentioned but ur's is less complex. accepting it !!

Answer (score 1):

If you're lucky enough not to have any spaces in any of the file systems:

```
df -kh | tr -s " " "\t"
```

will convert all runs of spaces into a single tab, for easy copy-pasting into Excel.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response but It's not working for me. when i try to run this command I am getting error : [No such file or directory]

Comment: @Gourabp OK, so just to be sure we're on the same page: You've opened a PuTTY connection to a unix/linux machine, typed in "`df -kh | tr -s " " "\t"`", and the unix/linux machine is telling you "[No such file or directory]"? If so, does running just "`tr`" give you the same message or something different? Also, if you could paste the entire message I might be able to help better.

Comment: I tried all the combination for ex : df -kh | tr  also giving me the same error message. only df -kh  is working as expected.

Comment: @Gourabp You should check to see if `sed` or `awk` is there, but if this unix/linux doesn't include basic text processing tools you may have to parse the output on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following way to formatt the output and really a nice formatted way to display the output :

df -Ph | perl -ne 'chomp; printf "\n%-60s %8s %8s %8s %8s %-10s", split / +/, $_, 6 ; '

The number 6 can be changed to any desirable value for me 6 is fine as I need letters.